# Ayuda con vista en sql

Tags: sql, base-de-datos, postgresql

estoy atrancado en un ejercicio para clase, el profe también me ha intentado ayudar y no ha acabado de salir... el enunciado es el siguiente:

Crear una vista, llamada top_patients, que recoja el paciente de cada ciudad que ha gastado más en visitas (a lo largo de todo el periodo). Concretamente se pide una lista de los pacientes, ordenada por el gasto en el que conste el nombre, el DNI, la ciudad y el gasto acumulado. (Busca la información necesaria para crear una vista en PostgreSQL)

El caso es que por separado si me da los resultados, es decir,  dni, y ciudad, y luego por separado, el gasto y el nombre, pero no consigo juntarlo todo como una sola tabla...

También os adjunto la descripción de las tablas patient y visit, que son las que se necesitan para el ejercicio:

PATIENT (Paciente)
La tabla contiene la información sobre los pacientes. De estos se guarda el número de paciente (Pat_Number, que es clave primaria), el nombre (Name), la dirección (Address), su ciudad (City), el número de identificación nacional (DNI) que es único para cada paciente pero puede ser nulo si no se dispone, y finalmente la fecha de la última visita (Last_Visit).

VISIT (Visita)
La tabla contiene la información sobre las visitas que los pacientes realizan los médicos. De cada visita se guarda la siguiente información: el número de colegiado del médico (Doc_Number), el número de paciente (Pat_Number), fecha de visita (Visit_Date), el importe (Price) que además no puede ser negativo.
La tripleta de atributos número de colegiado del médico (Doc_Number), el número de paciente (Pat_Number) y la fecha de la visita (Visit_Date) son la clave primaria de la tabla.
El número de colegiado del médico Doc_Number es clave foránea de MÉDICO (DOCTOR) y el número de paciente (Pat_Number) es clave foránea de PACIENTE (PATIENT).
Puede haber pacientes que no hayan realizado ninguna visita y médicos que no hayan atendido pacientes.

Y este es el código que llevo hasta ahora, a ver si me podéis ayudar en algo, muchas gracias de antemano! :D

```
set search_path to ubd_20151;

CREATE VIEW top_patients AS
select name, DNI
from Patient,(
select max("Despesa acumulada"), city  from (
select sum(price) as "Despesa acumulada", city, name, DNI
from visit, patient
where visit.Pat_Number = patient.Pat_Number
group by city, city, name, DNI
order by "Despesa acumulada") as inst
group by city) as inst2
group by name, DNI
```

Comment: Me parece que no es lo mismo pedir *Crear una vista, llamada top_patients, que recoja el paciente de cada ciudad que ha gastado más en visitas (a lo largo de todo el periodo)*, a diferencia de *Concretamente se pide una lista de los pacientes, ordenada por el gasto en el que conste el nombre, el DNI, la ciudad y el gasto acumulado. (Busca la información necesaria para crear una vista en PostgreSQL)*. ¿Cual de las 2 es la correcta?

Answer (score 0):

A mi me parece que estás pidiendo 2 cosas distintas.  Si lo que pides es:

> Crear una vista, llamada top_patients, que recoja el paciente de cada ciudad que ha gastado más en visitas (a lo largo de todo el periodo).

... entonces, esta es una forma de hacerlo:

```
create view top_patients as
with patient_despesa_acumuladas as (
    select p.pat_number,
           coalesce(sum(v.price), 0) despesa_acumulada
      from patient p
      left join visit v
        on v.pat_number = p.pat_number
     group by p.pat_number)
select p.pat_number,
       p.name,
       p.address,
       p.city,
       p.dni,
       p.last_visit
  from (select p.*,
               row_number() over (
                 partition by p.city
                 order by pda.despesa_acumulada desc) as rn
          from patient p
          join patient_despesa_acumuladas pda
            on pda.pat_number = p.pat_number) p
 where p.rn = 1
```

Pero por otro lado, también pides lo siguiente, que no me parece ser lo mismo:

> Concretamente se pide una lista de los pacientes, ordenada por el gasto en el que conste el nombre, el DNI, la ciudad y el gasto acumulado.

En este caso, la consulta pudiera ser:

```
create view top_patients as
with patient_despesa_acumuladas as (
    select p.pat_number,
           coalesce(sum(v.price), 0) despesa_acumulada
      from patient p
      left join visit v
        on v.pat_number = p.pat_number
     group by p.pat_number)
select p.name,
       p.dni,
       p.city,
       pda.despesa_acumulada
  from patient p
  join patient_despesa_acumuladas pda
    on pda.pat_number = p.pat_number
 order by pda.despesa_acumulada
```

La diferencia que yo veo, es que en el primer caso, solo quieres *un paciente por ciudad*, el que haya gastado más.  Pero en el segundo caso, quieres *todos los pacientes* ordenados por gasto. No es lo mismo.